# PowerPoint VBA - Click on shape then press another shape to change the colour

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to VBA (since this morning so please treat me like an idiot and you will be about right!) and am stuck on something that seems as though it should be very simple.

I am working in PowerPoint and have a set of circles and below them a red and a green coloured square.

I would like to be able to select a relevant circle and then click on the appropriate square to change that circle only to red or green, as below

```
 Select your option:   O         O          O              O             O


 Change colour:              [Red]                  [Green]
```

At the moment I am using animations and triggers but I have LOTS of circles and I only want to change them one at a time.

Comment: If you click a circle and then click the square, the focus will shift from Circle to Square. In such a case what you could do is use boolean variables which get `activated` when you click  particular circle and then use the code the color the relevant shape(circle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to Siddharth for that answer.  There's another bit that won't be apparent if you're just getting started out.  You can have PPT pass a reference to the clicked shape when the shape triggers a macro (caution:  Mac PPT is buggy/incomplete.  This won't work there).

Using Siddharth's suggestion as a jumping off point, you can do something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SelectMe(oSh As Shape)
' assign this macro to each of the shapes you want to color
' saves time to assign it to one shape, then copy the shape as many
' times as needed.
    ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "LastSelected", oSh.Name
End Sub
Sub ColorMeRed(oSh As Shape)
' assign this macro to the "color it red" shape

' when this runs because you clicked a shape assigned to run the macro,
' oSh will contain a reference to the shape you clicked

' oSh.Parent returns a reference to the slide that contains the shape
' oSh.Parent.Shapes(ActivePresentation.Tags("LastSelected")) returns a reference
' to the shape whose name is contained in the "LastSelected" tag,
' which was applied in the SelectMe macro above.
' Whew!

    If Len(ActivePresentation.Tags("LastSelected")) > 0 Then
        With oSh.Parent.Shapes(ActivePresentation.Tags("LastSelected"))
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
    End If

End Sub
Sub ColorMeBlue(oSh As Shape)
' assign this macro to the "color it blue" shape
    If Len(ActivePresentation.Tags("LastSelected")) > 0 Then
        With oSh.Parent.Shapes(ActivePresentation.Tags("LastSelected"))
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, both. I will sit down and try and work my way through this - see what I can understand!